# Calculate the duration between now and the next midnight using Chrono

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

What is the idiomatic way to get the duration between now and the next midnight?

I have a function like this:

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::prelude::*;
use time;

fn duration_until_next_midnight() -> time::Duration {
    let now = Local::now(); // Fri Dec 08 2017 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)
    // ... how to continue??
}
```

It should make a `Duration` with 1 hour, since the next midnight is *Sat Dec 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After scouring the docs, I finally found the missing link: [`Date::and_hms`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/struct.Date.html#method.and_hms).

So, actually, it's as easy as:

```
fn main() {
    let now = Local::now();

    let tomorrow_midnight = (now + Duration::days(1)).date().and_hms(0, 0, 0);

    let duration = tomorrow_midnight.signed_duration_since(now).to_std().unwrap();

    println!("Duration between {:?} and {:?}: {:?}", now, tomorrow_midnight, duration);
}
```

The idea is simple:

- increase the `DateTime` to tomorrow,
- extract the `Date` part, which keeps the timezone,
- reconstructs a new `DateTime` by specifying a "00:00:00" `Time` with `and_hms`.

There's a `panic!` in `and_hms`, so one has to be careful to specify a correct time.

Comment: `let tomorrow_midnight = now + Duration::days(1);` is sufficient. It will give tomorrow date, with 00:00:00 as time.

Comment: @azzamsa: The documentation and the playground disagree with your assessment, see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a84e6dfc4986df59342b5edec07485b1 and the latest example of https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDateTime.html#method.checked_add_signed

Answer (score 3):

Just subtract the two dates: midnight and now:

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::prelude::*;
use std::time;

fn duration_until_next_midnight() -> time::Duration {
    let now = Local::now();
    // change to next day and reset hour to 00:00
    let midnight = (now + chrono::Duration::days(1))
        .with_hour(0).unwrap()
        .with_minute(0).unwrap()
        .with_second(0).unwrap()
        .with_nanosecond(0).unwrap();

    println!("Duration between {:?} and {:?}:", now, midnight);
    midnight.signed_duration_since(now).to_std().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", duration_until_next_midnight())
}
```

As requested by Matthieu, you can write something like:

```
fn duration_until_next_midnight() -> Duration {
    let now = Local::now();
    // get the NaiveDate of tomorrow
    let midnight_naivedate = (now + chrono::Duration::days(1)).naive_utc().date();
    // create a NaiveDateTime from it
    let midnight_naivedatetime = NaiveDateTime::new(midnight_naivedate, NaiveTime::from_hms(0, 0, 0));
    // get the local DateTime of midnight
    let midnight: DateTime<Local> = DateTime::from_utc(midnight_naivedatetime, *now.offset());

    println!("Duration between {:?} and {:?}:", now, midnight);
    midnight.signed_duration_since(now).to_std().unwrap()
}
```

But I am not sure if it is better.

Comment: Is there a way to set hour/minute/second/nanoseconds in a single call? Would help quite a bit.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Unfortunately, it seems there is no way to do this with less boilerplate: https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/trait.Timelike.html

Comment: Maybe it would be simpler to extract the NaiveDate, and rebuild a NaiveDateTime from it, then build a new Date from this new NaiveDateTime and Timezone?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Even this seems difficult. The crate lacks some functions in my opinion: I wrote something as you suggest, but the code is less readable. IMO having an `impl From<Date> for DateTime` would be great, or even `DateTime::new(date: Date, time: Time)`.

Comment: To be honest, I was mostly aiming at reducing the amount of `unwrap`, so in this sense it's a net win.

Comment: Ah! Finally found a better way. We've been missing `Date::and_hms -> DateTime`: this (1) preserve the timezone and (2) does not require all the constructor dance. It's much neater with it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sorry, I didn't saw your answer

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are sorry for, so... hum... no worries?

Comment: I updated my answer thanks to your hint, without seeing that your added your own answer.

Comment: Oh, that's nothing to be sorry for! I certainly wouldn't have arrived to my answer without yours and our discussion; I actually upvoted your answer because it was useful to me :)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to calculate the seconds missing to next midnight, keeping in mind that [`time::Tm`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/time/time/struct.Tm.html) accounts for both Daylight Saving Time and time zones:

> tm_utcoff: i32
>
> Identifies the time zone that was used to compute this broken-down time value, including any adjustment for Daylight Saving Time. This is the number of seconds east of UTC. For example, for U.S. Pacific Daylight Time, the value is -7*60*60 = -25200.

```
extern crate time;
use std::time::Duration;

fn duration_until_next_midnight() -> Duration {
    let tnow = time::now();

    Duration::new(
        (86400 - tnow.to_timespec().sec % 86400 - 
        i64::from(tnow.tm_utcoff)) as u64,
        0,
    )
}
```

If you want nanoseconds precision you have to do some more maths ...

Comment: I'd use some aliases for readability maybe, like `let seconds_in_a_day = 24 * 3600`.

Answer (score 0):

For the next person who reaches here. Here is a version that uses the newer API as the most of the ones used in the top answer and now depricated.

```rust
let now = chrono::Local::now();

let tomorrow_midnight = (now + chrono::Duration::days(1))
    .date_naive()
    .and_hms_opt(0, 0, 0)
    .unwrap();

let duration = tomorrow_midnight
    .signed_duration_since(now.naive_local())
    .to_std()
    .unwrap();

println!(
    "Duration between {:?} and {:?}: {:?}",
    now, tomorrow_midnight, duration
);
```